# Implement a singleton for iAd Banner

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iad

Do any one know how to correctly implement one instance for an ADBanner and share it for all view controllers in my app ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the banner along as an instance variable as you create controllers?

Make the ad banner an instance variable on your app delegate?

Create a UIViewController category with an adBanner method that creates a static AdBanner if needed and returns it?

Comment: I had never thought of that third one...nice idea!

Comment: Should I create the static AdBanner instance in the AppDelegate ?

Comment: If you create an AdBanner instance in the app delegate, it doesn't need to be static. Just make it a retained property. If you go with a category, declare the static AdBanner in your category method.

Comment: I had implemented it like you said with a  #define SharedAdBannerView ((TourDeMagieAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).adBanner